# TypeScript : what does this variable declaration syntax mean?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Anyone know what does this mean :

```
myCollection: Collection|any = null;
```

?

I'm trying to figure it out but I am not sure..

Does it mean that myCollection is defined as a type of Collection, *(which is an interface)*, and that its value is null by default?
But if so, what does this :

```
|any
```

Means ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types).  The type `A | B` means "either `A` or `B` or both".

`any` is [the `any` "type"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any), which you generally [shouldn't be using](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any) because it effectively turns off type checking by being assignable both *to* any other type and *from* any other type.  This also means that `any` gobbles up any type that it appears with in a union or an intersection.

The type `Collection | any` therefore means "either a `Collection` or `any` type whatsoever".  This reduces immediately to just `any` by the compiler, since that "either A or anything" is just "anything":

```
myCollection: Collection | any = null;
// (property) Foo.myCollection: any
```

So `Collection | any` is at best useful for documentation; as far as the compiler is concerned, `Collection |` goes away.

And the property is initialized to `null`.

---

I'm not sure if this is someone else's code or yours.  If it's yours, consider changing to `Collection | null` if the intent is that the property can be a `Collection` or `null`.  If it's someone else's, uh, ask them what's up with it I guess?

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA2mILMdEZAbwFgAoZK5OALmQGcwpQBzAbgoF8LkKFMcBg2QAxdOhIVe1ALYBPDNlz5C9JTjwEiAHxoh5yALzIQAV2ydK1APQ3kACgAOUdE+hh5ASjESAdAoaKtr0cAbS5FxAA)

Answer (score 1):

It means that myCollection can be of type Collection or of type any and it is initialized to null

Answer (score 1):

In `Collection|any` this type, `|` indicates [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types)

Meaning of this is, variable `mycollection` can hold value of type `Collection` **OR** type of `any`.

Because `mycollection` can be of type `any`, `null` is valid value and typescript allows you to assign null to mycollection.